# How do I properly generate synthetic data for Poisson and exponential gammaproblems for the independent variables?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-generation

I need to generate a random data sample to do a Poisson and gamma regression problem. I can generate the targets using the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#generate first target with poisson distribution
target_1 = np.random.poisson(lam = 0.001, size = 1664697)
df = pd.DataFrame({'target_1': target_1})
df1 = df.loc[df['target_1'] == 0]
df2 = df.loc[df['target_1'] > 0]

#generate 2nd target with exponenetial distribution
gamma_size = df2.shape[0]
target_2 = np.random.exponential(scale = 1, size = gamma_size)
target_2 = target_2*33333
target2 = list(target_2)

#join target 1 > 0 to target 2
df2['target_2'] = target2
#concatenate and fill nas both target 1 == 0 and target 2
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index = True)
df.fillna(value = 0, inplace=True)
```

First question: How do I add continuous variables to this?
Lets say I want to add age, years of vehicle ownership, and vehicle type to this.  We will use age for an example of a continuous variable.  I have ages between 18 and 65.  I know that 2% of my `target_1 > 0` is age 26, and 30% of `target_1 == 0` is at age 26 and x% for the other ages.  How would I generate that data to append to this data set?

Second question: How do I add categorical variables to this?
I know that I have Harley, Sport and Street vehicles.  I know the percentage of those per `target_1` and per 'target_2`.  How would I generate and add those?

I will apply the above two to other variables.  Thank you.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can pass probability weights into numpy's random.choice function, based on weights generated by your distributions

Comment: A good process when producing synthetic data with a dependency structure is to draw out your dependency graph, generate the most independent variables with the frequency/parametrised distribution they have in the base population, then generate variables that are dependent on those parametrised by the independent variables. If you need your dependent variables to have some specific distribution, you can use something like rejection sampling to select a suitably-distributed subset. This should preserve the desired dependencies between variables.

Comment: Thank you @RHill.  Do you have a recommended tutorial in python to do this?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't. It's not Python-specific, and is highly dependent on what you want to achieve with your data. Rejection sampling is a fairly well-established method of generating random values that conform to a specified distribution, though, so you should be able to find plenty of instructive material online.